# How can I pass variable to ejs.compile

Tags: node.js, ejs

My bottom_index.ejs looks like that:

```
<div>The bottom section</div>
```

In my code I declare ejs:

```
ejs = require('ejs');
```

Then compile the function:

```
var botom_index_ejs =
ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../views/bottom_index.ejs", 'utf8'));
```

and then call it to get rendered html:

```
botom_index_ejs()
```

It works fine!

Now I would like to change my template to:

```
<div><%= bottom_text %></div>
```

and be able to pass the parameter (bottom_text) to the bottom_index.ejs

How should I pass the parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Parameters are passed to EJS template as a JS plain object. For your example it sholud be:

```
botom_index_ejs({ bottom_text : 'The bottom section' });
```

**Update:**

test.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var compiled = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/test.ejs', 'utf8'));
var html = compiled({ title : 'EJS', text : 'Hello, World!' });
console.log(html);
```

test.ejs

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><%= text %></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried and I've got bottom_text is not defined. Can you give a small working Hello world example please? It's important for me to use "compile" function, not just any working solution. Thank you.