# How to pass bearer authorization to a new page

Tags: javascript, authorization, token, bearer-token

I have pages that are only accessible if the bearer authorization token is passed in the header. When I click on a link to change the page of the site, how do I pass the token using javascript?

Comment: this problem is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453206/how-to-include-access-token-in-the-http-header-when-requesting-a-new-page-from-b).

Comment: In that topic there is not an exhaustive answer. In my case the server expects me to pass bearer authorization to reply with the page content. I have to find a client-side way to pass the token when I switch pages.